# How do I plot random points inside a circle using OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

How do I plot random points inside a circle? I have the following code that plots random points but I can't seem to figure out how to plot them inside a circle! I've been using the distance formula to generate random points with no luck. I expected to generate points within a circle but instead i just got a blank screen. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#define __gl_h_
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

struct Point
{
    float x, y;
    unsigned char r, g, b, a;
};
std::vector< Point > points;

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-50, 50, -50, 50, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();



    // draw
    glColor3ub( 255, 255, 255 );
    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glEnableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );
    glVertexPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Point), &points[0].x );
    glColorPointer( 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sizeof(Point), &points[0].r );
    glPointSize( 3.0 );
    glDrawArrays( GL_POINTS, 0, points.size() );
    glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glDisableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutCreateWindow("Random Points");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

    // populate points
    for( size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i )
    {
        Point pt;
        //pt.x = -50 + (rand() % 100);
        //pt.y = -50 + (rand() % 100);


        int angle = (rand() % 100 + 1) * 3.1416 * 2;
        int radius = (rand() % 100 + 1) * 50;
        pt.x = ((radius * cos(angle))-50);
        pt.y = ((radius * sin(angle))-50);


        pt.r = 125;
        pt.g = 125;
        pt.b = 125;
        pt.a = 255;
        points.push_back(pt);
    }

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) What did you do? (you already answered this). 2) What did you expect to happen? 3) What actually happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Your angle is `int` in radians**

   so it got truncated only to angles `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6} [rad]` so you cannot cover the inside of circle just those `7` lines.
2. **you are mixing `int` and `double` while computation**

   without proper casting it could got truncated (depends on the compiler). If you realize `sin,cos` are in range `<-1,+1>` after truncation you got just `{-1,0,+1}` which will generate just `9` possible angles. (with combination with **#1** even less so you render just few points and most likely did not recognize them in view).
3. **I do not use your `rand()` so I am not sure what it returns.**

   My bet that it returns integer in range up to some `RAND_MAX` value.

   I am used to **VCL** style `Random()` which have two options:

   ```
   double Random();     // return pseudo-random floating number in range <0.0,1.0)
   int Random(int max); // return pseudo-random integer number in range <0,max)
   ```

   So if your `rand()` is similar then you are truncating the result to `{0}` render it useless. Consult the documentation of your `rand()` to see if it is integer or floating and change accordingly if needed.
4. **You are most likely shifting the center outside view**

   you are substracting `50` from value in range `<-50,+50>` that shift it to `<-100,0>` which I bet is outside your screen. I am too lazy to analyse your code but I think your screen is `<-50,+50>` so try to not shift at all

When put all together try this instead:

```
double angle = double(rand() % 1000) * 6.283185307179586476925286766559;
int   radius = rand() % 51;
pt.x = double(double(radius)*cos(angle));
pt.y = double(double(radius)*sin(angle));
```

Comment: For random numbers you have [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That just gives me a straight line of points to the right.

Comment: @NicholasGenco your `cos` and `sin` want angle in radians or degrees?